# Why do humans have eyebrows?

Tags: evolution, human-eye

Why do humans have eyebrows? It seems that it isn't necessary but only humans have them, correct? So what is the use of them for humans? I hear that they protect our eyes. However, isn't that what eyelashes do? What other functions do eyelashes have?

Comment: I think apes have them,  look up chimpanzee picture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eyebrows function to protect the eyes from perspiration and provide shade.
>
> Eyelids function to protect the eyes from foreign objects and sunlight.
>
> Eyelashes function to protect the eyes from foreign objects, produce sebum (a lubriant that the eyelids) and acts as protection for the eyes from tears [[1]](http://www.emergencymedicalparamedic.com/what-is-the-function-of-eyebrows-eyelids-and-eyelashes/).

The above seems to be backed up by [health how stuff works](http://health.howstuffworks.com/human-body/systems/eye/question520.htm) and [the anatomy of the eye](http://www.emedicinehealth.com/anatomy_of_the_eye/page3_em.htm) from emedicinehealth.

However, note that biologist dont have any concrete reasons for the eyebrow. This is just what many of them agree on I suppose. Here is another resource from [sciencefocus](http://www.sciencefocus.com/qa/why-do-we-have-eyebrows).

Comment: What about facial expressions?